# Password from .bin file

Tags: binary

I am trying to find a password for a bin file for an plc.

a real pain. anyone here that have a idea ?

https://filebin.net/r673zgmbl5ecxtdw/LOGO_U_P.bin

Comment: It doesn't really have much content... lots of spaces and nulls, are you sure this is real content?

Comment: yes, it is a plc program that is running, but i want to change some functions for it in logosoft